# How to use filter_complex on ffmpeg with streaming videos

Tags: ffmpeg, ffserver

I have 30 video sources. i want to make ffmpeg command to create 1 channel (streaming) with all channels embedded in (in bad quality)

```
"[0:v][1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,overlay=20:40[1]; \
 [1][1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[v]; \
 [1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 3.mp4
```

i trying to find the correct command do downgrade quality, than create one streaming output. (one audio chosen)

Comment: Not sure what *one audio chosen* means. Do all of the inputs have audio? Do you need to downmix them all, or do you have a separate audio stream/input that you want to include in the output?

Comment: i need one stream with 30 videos and 1 audio, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scale each video to desired size with the [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale). Arrange with the [xstack filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xstack).

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 ... -i input29 -i audio -filter_complex
"[0]scale=128:-1[v0];[1]scale=128:-1[v1];...[29]scale=128:-1[v29];
[v0][v1]...[v29]xstack=inputs=30:layout=<your desired layout>[v]"
-map "[v]" -map 30:a -c:v libx264 -crf 51 -c:a aac -shortest output.mp4
```

`-crf 51` will provide the low quality as requested. Decrease the value if you want better quality.